# C++ template parameter deduction fails

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits

Why compiler can deduce T with this code:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void foo(T& t) {}

int main(void) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> vec = { 1,2,3 };
    foo(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

But fails with this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void foo(typename std::enable_if<true, T>::type& t) {}

int main(void) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> vec = { 1,2,3 };
    foo(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use second construct, to select between two template functions, based on passed class method existence.

Comment: There could be a specialization `std::enable_if<true, MyType>` which contains a `using type = std::vector<uint8_t>`. How is the compiler to know when it only has the parameter type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained by vsoftco, you have a non-deduced context.

For SFINAE, you may use one of the following:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<condition_dependent_of_T, ReturnType>
foo(T& t) {}
```

or

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<condition_dependent_of_T>* = nullptr>
ReturnType foo(T& t) {}
```

Comment: It works great. But I can not understand why condition_dependent_of_T must really depend on T. When I put there evaluated constants, code fails to compile, why is that?

Comment: @omicronns `T` is deduced from the argument `T& t`, not from the `enable_if`. The non-deduced contexts are non-deducible because it is extremely hard (and sometime impossible) for a compiler to deduce the type from them. The `enable_if` **should** depend on `T` as `T` will be deduced, then SFINAE will kick in.

Comment: @Jarod42 I wish one can merge answers on SO :)

Comment: I understand now. When I put constants enable_if::type gets evaluated same for both calls. When I parametrize it due to T, it gets evaluated differently for different calls. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In the second case you have a [*non-deduced context*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), in other words, the compiler cannot deduce the type.

The simplest example of a non-deduced context is

```
template<typename T>
struct Id
{
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
void foo(typename Id<T>::type arg); // T cannot be deduced
```

Comment: To solve the problem it is needed to separate context for deduction and enable_if. Common practise is to use enable_if in function return value, like this: `template<typename T>
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::vector<uint8_t>>::value, void>::type foo(T& t) {}`

Answer (score 2):

To visualize the problem let's analyse an example:

```
template <class>
struct foo { 
    using type = float;
};

template <>
struct foo<bool> {
    using type = int;
};

template <>
struct foo<int> {
    using type = int;
};

template <class T>
void bar(foo<T>::type t) { }

int main() {
   bar(int{}); 
}
```

Now in the line `bar(int{});` both types `bool` as well as `int` matches to a template parameter `T`. Which one value should be deduced then? This is only the one example why non-deduced context is strictly necessary!

Comment: Ok. But the compilers knows those ambiguous specializations by bar call. When foo<bool> is not present (or foo<int>) then there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @omicronns Yeah but then imagine how many rules and exceptions need to be added to an already super complicated set of rules. And sometime the compiler may not know: what if your specializations are defined in different compilation units? The compiler is not making any assumptions about other units.

Comment: @vsoftco So this limitation is provided to not overcomplicate compilers?

Comment: @omicronns I think it's genuinely impossible, see the edited comment.